# what is "powers of 2" and "word"?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm recently following C++ Primer Book In chapter 2
and I'm at this point

> Most computers deal with memory as chunks of bits of sizes that are powers of 2. The smallest chunk of addressable memory is referred to as a “byte.” The basic unit of storage, usually a small number of bytes, is referred to as a “word.” In C++ a byte has at least as many bits as are needed to hold a character in the machine’s basic character set. On most machines a byte contains 8 bits and a word is either 32 or 64 bits, that is, 4 or 8 bytes.

> Most computers associate a number (called an “address”) with each byte in memory. On a machine with 8-bit bytes and 32-bit words, we might view a word of memory as follows

I don't understand well what does he mean with chunks of bits of sizes that are powers of 2
and what's a word also? he say a small number of bytes but that's not clear for me, can anyone explain?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

Comment: The first paragraph is pretty clear on the definition of "word", so I'm not sure what you're asking for here. Powers of 2 literally means 2 raised to a given exponent, e.g. 2³ (8 bit byte), 2⁵ or 2⁶ (32 or 64 bit word), etc.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ofc I know that since it's basic mathematics but it wasn't clear (obviously because my english level) anyway thanks, it's clear now

Comment: It means the CPU always operates data chucks of sizes that are powers of 2, so 1 byte, 2 bytes, 4, and 8 (usually stop there). You wont see a CPU that has an opcode to operate, say, 3 bytes for instance, unless it's some ASIC. A word is a data chunk bigger than 1 byte, usually used to refer to 2 bytes, as the 4 bytes is usually referred to as double word.

Comment: In spite of its goals, the C++ Primer is a far better reference book than it is a learning book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"chunks of bits of sizes that are powers of 2"
```

This means that most standard units of memory you'll encounter have a "width" (or size) contains a number of bits, and that number of bits is generally a power-of-two. A byte nearly always today contains 8 bits. The term "word" is frankly a little archaic at this point for modern programming (the book you're reading is a classic but it's not super contemporary!); a "word" is usually more than  a byte, traditionally 2 bytes (16 bits) or 4 bytes (32 bits), but this doesn't come up very often in a practical sense except in the names of some types or in system programming contexts.

Computers (in the sense of CPU chips) for engineering design reasons will generally only operate internally on chunks that are these sizes. What sizes are common has changed through time.

Most typical computers today (your cell phone, your laptop) are 64-bit systems, meaning the basic unit of data that the CPU operates on is 64 bits, or 8 bytes, wide.

The standard integer types you use in your program will generally correspond to one of these powers-of-two widths, and those will map to precise stuff for the machine to use in the machine language.

Answer (score 2):

> what is “powers of 2”

Powers of two are the numbers that can be represented as 2<sup>x</sup>, x ∈ ℤ

Among those numbers are: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...

---

> and what's a word also?

Here is the synopsis from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)):

> In computing, a word is the natural unit of data used by a particular processor design.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique definition of a word, nor even of a byte.

In the C language, a byte is a small integer able to represent the characters from the machine character set, without more specification.

In most other contexts, a byte is 8 bits.

A word can designate a *machine word*, i.e. correspond to the register size. That can indeed be 32 or 64 bits, but used to be 16 bits in the 80's.

Under the Windows API, a WORD is two bytes, while four bytes make a DOUBLEWORD and eight bytes a QUADWORD.